# Laravel- Show errors on the login page when login credentials are wrong

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I am new to Laravel. I am designing an login page and I want to show the errors on login page itself when the login credentials are wrong. I haven't done anything in controller. I am using the inbuilt Laravel function-Auth. Here is my view code given below:

```
<div class="card">
    <div class="card-header">{{ __('Login') }}</div>

    <div class="card-body">
        <form method="POST" action="{{ route('login') }}" aria-label="{{ __('Login') }}">
            @csrf

            <div class="form-group row">
                <label for="email" class="col-sm-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __('E-Mail Address') }}</label>

                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <input id="email" type="email" class="form-control{{ $errors->has('email') ? ' is-invalid' : '' }}" name="email" value="{{ old('email') }}" required autofocus>

                    @if ($errors->has('email'))
                        <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                            <strong>{{ $errors->first('email') }}</strong>
                        </span>
                    @endif
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group row">
                <label for="password" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __('Password') }}</label>

                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <input id="password" type="password" class="form-control{{ $errors->has('password') ? ' is-invalid' : '' }}" name="password" required>

                    @if ($errors->has('password'))
                        <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                            <strong>{{ $errors->first('password') }}</strong>
                        </span>
                    @endif
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group row">
                <div class="col-md-6 offset-md-4">
                    <div class="checkbox">
                        <label>
                            <input type="checkbox" name="remember" {{ old('remember') ? 'checked' : '' }}> {{ __('Remember Me') }}
                        </label>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group row mb-0">
                <div class="col-md-8 offset-md-4">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
                        {{ __('Login') }}
                    </button>

                    <a class="btn btn-link" href="{{ route('password.request') }}">
                        {{ __('Forgot Your Password?') }}
                    </a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
```

Comment: You already have validations and you can adapt message in lang

Comment: In lang file, I have used these statements:
'failed' => 'These credentials do not match our records.',
'throttle' => 'Too many login attempts. Please try again in :seconds seconds.' ,

Comment: Could you please share your controller code?

Answer (score 0):

**Controller Redirection:**

```
Redirect::back()->withErrors(['errormsg', 'Try Again']);
```

**Blade file:**

```
@if($errors->any())
  <h4>{{$errors->first()}}</h4>
@endif
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this code and check.

```
if(Auth::attempt($user_data))
{
  return redirect('/');
}
else
{
  return redirect()->back()->withErrors(['error','Wrong Login Details']);
}
```

and put this code in login blade file.

```
@if($errors->any())
  <h4>{{$errors->first()}}</h4>
@endif
```